# Java two dots at the end of a path have unexpected results

Tags: java, windows

I've run into what I thought was unusual behavior when working with some File objects.

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\x..");

        System.out.println(file.isDirectory());

        System.out.println(file.listFiles());
    }
}
```

Assuming that some directory `C:\x` exists, `file.isDirectory()` will return true with the added two dots at the end of the path. This replicates the behavior in the command line, where `cd x..` will change the directory to `x`.

However, when calling `file.listFiles()`, the method returns null, which is only supposed to happen if the file is not a directory. This seems to be inconsistent with the definition of the `listFiles()`.

Why is this so? And why does having two dots at the end of the path go to the same directory as if there was no dots?

This problem seems to be exclusive to Windows. Linux correctly (?) returns false for `isDirectory()`.

Comment: `x..` is not a valid path (in that it does't exist), however `x\\..` might...

Comment: on Mac OS, cd x/.. changes directory back to x, are you sure cd x.. works on Windows ?

Comment: I thought it wasn't a valid path either, but it `isDirectory()` claims that it is both valid and is an existing directory.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Yes, I tested `cd x..` in that exact form. It should (?) be a separate command from `cd x/..`, which goes into `x` and then goes up a folder. `cd x..` just goes into `x`. And I don't think it can be replicated on Macs. I couldn't on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows trims trailing dots from path and filenames. I am unable to find a concrete reference for this, it's just one of those mysterious things that has always been that way.

It trims the trailing dots from the full pathname, not the individual components.

Therefore, while "C:\x...." is the same as "C:\x", "C:\x....\filename" is not the same as "C:\x\filename", as the latter does not have *trailing* dots.

You would have to look at the JDK's native `FileSystem` source on Windows to see precisely how it is obtaining a list of files, but I suspect it's doing some kind of search on e.g. "C:\x..\*.*" using Windows' `FindFirstFile` API call or something, where the dots are no longer trailing. In other words, presuming "C:\x" is a directory, while the path "C:\x.." is a directory, "C:\x..\*.*" matches nothing, and "C:\x..\subdirectory" does not map to "C:\x\subdirectory".

You should avoid using such paths. I'm not sure how you obtained that path string in the first place.

You can use `File.getCanonicalPath()` or `File.getCanonicalFile()` to convert it back to a more useable pathname.

By the way, if you want to have some fun with Windows, type the following in a command prompt (assuming "c:\windows\temp" exists, otherwise replace with some other path):

```
echo > \\?\c:\windows\temp\x.
```

The `\\?\` prefix in Windows disables filename processing and expansion. Now delete the resulting file. Try it in Explorer too.

Spoiler:

> You'll have to delete it with a wildcard from the console, e.g. `del x?`

Comment: My current project sports a file-browser-like window that includes a location bar. When playing around with that location bar to make sure it worked, I encountered this issue. So basically the user can enter such a path that the program thinks the entry is a valid directory, yet `listFiles()` won't like.

Comment: You can resolve it with `getCanonicalFile()` or `getCanonicalPath()` first.

Comment: By the way, if you want to have some fun with windows, type `echo > \\?\c:\windows\temp\x.` in a command prompt. Challenge: Delete the resulting file in explorer.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add extra slashes before `..` to it should be `c:\\x\\..`. This will point you to `C:` indeed

Comment: I don't read the OPs question as "how can I get this working" but rather as "why does it behave inconsistently". You are answering the first.

Comment: I'm aware of using `../` to go up a folder, and understand why it should work with the added slash. I'm more curious as to why it behaviors the way it does in the example.